# Sortable list won't sort (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, templates, model-view-controller

I have just refactored one of my sections of code and found that a sortable list that used to sort fine no-longer sorts. The `Javascript/JQuery` code is as follows:

```
function makeSortable() { 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
      $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
      console.log("sort function started");
    });
  };
```

The `Javascript` that calls it looks like this:

```
var UrlString = "http://orderofthemouse.co.uk/templates/menu/Formation.html";
loadDoc(UrlString);
makeSortable();
```

And the HTML template looks like this:

```
<h1>Formation</h1>
<h2>Drag characters to change positions</h2>
<ol class='sortable' id='charlist'>
  <li>
    <h3 class='charname'>Dragon-Bear</h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3 class='charname'>Deer-Wolf</h3>
  </li>
</ol>
```

The `LoadDoc()` function runs as follows:

```
function loadDoc(UrlString) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  console.log("URL = " + UrlString);
  xhttp.open("GET", UrlString, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The program definitely enters the function as the "sort function started" statement is logged to the console...

Comment: Post a minmal, failing jsfiddle.net please

Comment: Will do, gimme a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loadDoc` sounds asynchronous so that means you are not waiting until the content is loaded. So you are trying to attach events to elements that do not exist. You need to do it after you add the content.

A simple `console.log("sort function started", "length:", $( ".sortable" ).length);` will confirm that is the case.

Comment: I checked and length returns as 0, so this does seem to be the issue. Do I just need to implement a callback to fix this?

Comment: I do not know what loadDoc does, but yes, you would need to call it when the content is loaded.

Comment: LoadDoc() just loads in the appropriate MVC template. I'll add the code.